# Android layouts in Photoshop

Tags: android, xml, layout, photoshop, layer

is there a plugin for designing android layouts in photoshop? Creating android XML layouts is unnecessarily tedious (especially with having to type "android:" for every parameter, and typing out the layout parameters on every function when they might as well be auto-included when you begin the opening tag for that element), this is a factor of the tools available.

I'm sure people pride themselves in typing it out, but remember HTML elitists that brag about coding in notepad? Analogy: You CAN use a wrench a to drive a nail into wood, but there are better tools.

I imagine that photoshop's slice tool and html export tool could EASILY be configured to save for android XML, layers could be RelativeLayouts with the positioning intact. Has anybody done this already?

Comment: You don't have to type "android:" all the time. You can instead use "a:" as a namespace prefix if you wish. No one is forcing "android:" on you if you don't like typing that word :)

Comment: Somewhat related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/929875/good-gui-design-tool-to-mock-up-iphone-android-applications

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this tool, not perfect, but usable:

http://www.droiddraw.org/

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you use the ADT plugin in eclipse? The latest version released a few weeks ago includes a pretty good graphical editor.

Comment: I do, its rubbish for any layout with more than one Layout element, have you ever used layers in photoshop? Thats how it should work

Comment: Have you tried the latest version? It has come a long way, it is yet to be on par with the Interface Builder though.

Comment: Hm, last android build I have is 3.0 so I guess since 3.2 I have to upgrade, I'll let you know